# how to get id value from listview on the ClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to get the id from the `listview`, not the position. The id is in the JSON file so while I am displaying the data in a `listview` so when I click on it I get the id of that driver from JSON file.

> [{lastName=wdkj fsj, firstName=jf jfn, id=1}, {lastName=singh,
>   firstName=sunny, id=2}]

```
public class DriverData extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String TAG = DriverData.class.getSimpleName();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListView lv;


    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "http://54.148.120.200:3000/getDrivers";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.driver_data);

        contactList = new ArrayList<>();
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.simpleListView);


        new DriverData.GetContacts().execute();


    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DriverData.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("drivers");

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString("id");
                        JSONObject user = c.getJSONObject("user");
                        String firstName = user.getString("firstName");
                        String lastName = user.getString("lastName");


                        // Phone node is JSON Object


                        // tmp hash map for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put("id", id);
                        contact.put("firstName", firstName);
                        contact.put("lastName", lastName);

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);


                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }
            System.out.println(contactList);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();



            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    DriverData.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"firstName", "lastName"
            }, new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.lastName});
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are want to get ID from JSON?

Comment: try to learn first java as well as JSON also. :)

Comment: when user click on the display listview(that has all the drivers first name and last name) and it has the id of the driver i want that id

Comment: Simply your processes. 1.Create your custom adapter. 2.Create POJO file and put all your data. 3. Send only POJO list to your Constructor of Custom Adapter.

Comment: @javadKhan is there any example?

Comment: @SunnySingh there are millions of examples everywhere ;). Now i'll give you example in answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have it in contactList, you can simply retrieve it.

Do this inside setOnItemClickListener()

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            String id=contactList.get(position).get("id");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all create POJO model for saving objects and using them easily.

```
public class Contact {

    private String id;
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;

    public Contact(String id, String lastName, String firstName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
}
```

This is simply POJO model class, but if you want to get more information about this, you can follow this [link](https://medium.com/android-testing-daily/the-power-of-pojos-fac4117d5707)!

**Note** : Variables should be `private` and methods should be `public`.

Then, it will be better if you create your own custom adapter.

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    private List<Contact> contactList;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Contact> contactList) {
        super(context, resource, contactList);
        this.contactList = contactList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.itemlistrow, null);
        }

        Item p = getItem(position);

        if (p != null) {
            TextView tvId = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.id);
            TextView tvLastName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lastName);
            TextView tvFirstName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.firstName);

            tvId.setText(contactList.getId()); // this will show ID
            tvLastName.setText(contactList.getLastName()); 
            tvFirstName.setText(contactList.getFirstName());

        }

        return v;
    }

}
```

Then, after getting all data from JSON link, send data to constructor. 
I'll update your source:

```
      try {
                contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>;
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("drivers");

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    Contact contact = new Contact();

                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);


                    JSONObject user = c.getJSONObject("user");
                    contact.setId(c.getString("id"));
                    contact.setFirstName(user.getString("firstName"));
                    contact.setLastName(user.getString("lastName"));

                    contactList.add(contact);


                }
            }
```

Update your `onPostExecute()` method also.

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();


            //System.out.println(contactList.size());

            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */

            ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(
                    getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, contactList);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

If you get any error, comment here, and i'll update. Not tested yet, but i think this will helpful. Enjoy!